# I have this 'space' underneath my navigation bar

Tags: html

I'm a total noob at this... I did the whole code academy classes, can't seem to find an answer to my problem anywhere. Basically my site is centralised, from top to bottom it goes;

Logo
Navigation Bar
{Huge random space)
Picture
Copyright note

It's this space I'm trying to get rid of so that the space I have between my logo and the nav bar matches the space between the nav bar and the picture...

Here is my HTML;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Access All Areas - Fashion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="min-width: 960px; min-height: 760px; margin: 0 auto;">
<!-- AAA Logo -->
<div class="image">
    <center>
    <img src="a1.jpg" alt="Access All Areas Logo" width="750px"           
height="320px">
    </center>
</div>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
<div class="nav">
    <center>
    <ul>
    <li class="main"><a href="main.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="live"><a href="live.html">LIVE</a></li>
    <li class="studio"><a href="studio.html">STUDIO</a></li>
    <strong><li class="fashion"><a href="fashion.html">FASHION</a></li> 
</strong>
    <li class="weddings"><a href="weddings.html">WEDDINGS</a></li>
    <li class="portraits"><a href="portraits.html">PORTRAITS</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </center>
</div><!--Nav-->
</div><!--Style-->
<!--COVER IMAGE-->
<center>
<div class="cover">
<img src="images/fashion.jpg" alt="Access All Areas Fashion Image"   
width="1400px" height="2300px">
</center>
</div><!--Cover-->
<!--Copyright-->
<center>
<div id="copyright">
<p><strong>ALL RIGHTS RESERVED ACCESS ALL AREAS PHOTOGRAPHY</p></strong>
</div><!--Copyright-->
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS;

```
li {
display:inline;
}

.nav a {
font-family:arial;
font-size:18px;
color: black;
padding:0px 75px 0px 25px;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
}

.cover {
margin-top:0px;
}

.main {
text-weight:strong;
}

p {
font-family:arial;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

I really hope someone can help me. Another couple of things I'm looking to do is to relocate the copyright text to the bottom left of the image and also make a grid of different sized images and have no idea where to start.

Many thanks

Peter James

Comment: I hope code academy isn't teaching anyone to use `<center>`. Also, `min-height: 760px;` seems to be your culprit.

Comment: No I googled how to do something and found that worked. if there's a better way to do something I'll change it. I want to learn all this

Comment: Ok, here's the link for the center element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center. I highly recommend learning from https://developer.mozilla.org/

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thankyou, your comment sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have been great and easy to solve your problem, if you had provided us with a jsfiddle. But anyway, I think `min-height` is causing the problem. As you have forcing the header to be 670px tall. See here http://jsfiddle.net/0v4fsg6z/  I have reduced the height to remove the space before Picture Copyright note.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and set your `img` tag to `position: absolute`?
[image: fixed]
[image: unfixed]

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't do what I want it to do. Instead it aligns left and buggers up the rest of the layout. I'm more or less happy now that the min height was the issue. I entered that in to do something with stopping the layout from going haywire on a resize event. that's sorted now, the only thing now is the main image moves with the window as the position is central to the window and not the layout....

Comment: Oh right, well I am glad you got it sorted! :]

Happy developing.

Comment: Notepad++ or WebStorm :]